# Uncaught Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have WordPress version 4.7.5  and WooCommerce 3.1.1

when I try to add some attribute the page enters on a loading loop.
Then I open the browser inspect console (chrome) the message error is there, a lot of errors. That’s the message:

```
Uncaught Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.
    at String.<anonymous> (select2.min.js:21)
    at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery…:2)
    at d.prepareOpts (select2.min.js:21)
    at d.prepareOpts (select2.min.js:22)
    at d.init (select2.min.js:21)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (select2.min.js:22)
    at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery…:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery…:2)
    at a.fn.init.a.fn.select2 (select2.min.js:22)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (wc-enhanced-select.min.js:1)
```

Comment: What for options have you defined in the select2 plugin?